# SQL Query - Group and SUM of Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following database structure:

ID | Payment (Decimal) | PaymentDate (DateTime) | PaymentStatus(int)

I am currently able to get a grouping of all of the payments over time by Year and Date and get the total across all Payment Status's using the following query;

```
Select 
YEAR = YEAR(DueDate),
MONTH = MONTH(DueDate),
MMM = UPPER(left(DATENAME(MONTH,DueDate),3)),
Totals = sum(Payment)
from 
PaymentSchedules
Where DueDate IS NOT NULL
Group by 
YEAR(DueDate),
MONTH(DueDate),
DATENAME(Month,DueDate)
Order By
YEAR,
MONTH
```

This gives me the results so far so good.

[image]

What I would like to be able to do is have added totals for the splits in each section.  So for example if each payment could be Paid (1) or Unpaid (2) or Overdue (3) I would like to not only get the number of paid / unpaid / overdue but I would also like to get the total value of unpaid items / paid items / Overdue items for each Year / Month combination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add `SUM`s with `CASE` statements inside to only sum payments when the correct status is detected, like this:

```
Select YEAR = YEAR(DueDate),
       MONTH = MONTH(DueDate),
       MMM = UPPER(left(DATENAME(MONTH,DueDate),3)),
       TotalPaid = sum(case when PaymentStatus = 1 then Payment else 0 end),
       TotalUnpaid = sum(case when PaymentStatus = 2 then Payment else 0 end),
       TotalOverdue = sum(case when PaymentStatus = 3 then Payment else 0 end),
       Totals = sum(Payment)
from PaymentSchedules
Where DueDate IS NOT NULL
Group by YEAR(DueDate),
         MONTH(DueDate),
         DATENAME(Month,DueDate)
Order By YEAR,
         MONTH
```

Comment: Thank you..this is perfect and i have learnt something new :)

Comment: One additional query..the Sum is working great, but when i tried to do a TOTAL of the paid (i.e how many payments are paid for that time) it wasn't working...granted all i did was change SUM for COUNT.. I am guessing this isn't right?

Also whats the "then payment else 0" part of the query mean?

Comment: If you changed `sum` to `count`, that would change the meaning, yes.  `sum(payment)` actually sums the values of `payment` for each processed row, where as `count(payment)` will give you the number of rows where the value of `payment` was not null.

Comment: `case when PaymentStatus = 1 then Payment else 0 end`: basically says that if the current row's `PaymentStatus` value is `1` (paid), then sum the value of `Payment`. Otherwise, sum the value `0`, in other words, don't sum anything if `PaymentStatus` is ***not*** `1` (paid).

Comment: Does that mean that if i wanted to get the total number of payments that is paid simply changing the sum to count wouldnt work. Based on your description of it counting where not null..would you be able to provide an example?  Thanks again

Comment: I'm slightly confused. But let's see if I understand... If what you want is the total ***value*** of the payments, then you would want to use `sum`.  But if you are interested in counting the ***number*** of payments, without caring about the actual payment amount, then `count` is the right call.

Comment: Thats right..but when i change sum to count it gives me the same numbers for each one and seems to ignore the case statement..

Comment: add `TotalPaidCount = sum(case when PaymentStatus = 1 then 1 else 0 end)`

Comment: A little [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2b6b5/2) is you want to better understand how `sum` and `count` work.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are only 3 categories, I would suggest use CASE statement directly.

```
Select 
YEAR = YEAR(DueDate),
MONTH = MONTH(DueDate),
MMM = UPPER(left(DATENAME(MONTH,DueDate),3)),
Paid_sum = sum(CASE When PaymentStatus = 1 THEN Payment ELSE 0 END),
Unpaid_sum = sum(CASE When PaymentStatus = 2 THEN Payment ELSE 0 END),
Overdue_sum = sum(CASE When PaymentStatus = 3 THEN Payment ELSE 0 END),
Totals = sum(Payment)
from 
PaymentSchedules
Where DueDate IS NOT NULL
Group by 
YEAR(DueDate),
MONTH(DueDate),
DATENAME(Month,DueDate)
Order By
YEAR,
MONTH
```